# Limit Woocommerce featured products in a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I want to get 3 featured products in the header of the site. But my query keeps returning unlimited number of results.

I've been looking online for a solution and came across answers that all answer saying the same thing in terms of the query. What could I be doing wrong?

```
$meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN',
);

$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => 2,
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
    'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {

    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : 

        $featured_query->the_post();

        $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );

        echo $product->title; echo "test";
        // Product info here

    endwhile;

}

wp_reset_query();
```

The following query returned 20 results. The code was placed in header.php. Using woocommerce 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your code is a bit outdated, since Woocommerce 3, as `get_product()` need to be replaced with `wc_get_product()` and `$product->title;` by `$product->get_title();`… 
Once done your code works and you will get 3 featured products:

```
$meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN',
);

$featured = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => 3, // <==  <==  <==  3 products
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
    'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
) );

// Get the products count in the query
echo '<p>Featured products count: ' .$featured->post_count . '</p>';

if ($featured->have_posts()) : while ($featured->have_posts()) : 
    $featured->the_post();

    $product = wc_get_product( $featured->post->ID );

    echo $product->get_title() . '<br>';
    // Product info here

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

It should work for you as I have tested successfully this code on header.php file…

> As before Woocommerce 3, the "featured products" where handled by post meta data (a meta query), you may need to update product terms count going to Woocommerce settings > status > tools. In **"Term counts"** section click on "Recount terms".

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) instead of [`wp_reset_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) since `WP_query` doesn't overwrite the main query.

If that doesn't solve your issue, make sure any other custom loops use the appropriate reset, and/or try renaming the variable `$featured_query` if you're using it elsewhere - it may be inheriting posts from a previous loop.

You could also try adding the `'nopaging' => true` and `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` arguments

I hate to suggest it, but if you can't figure out why it's returning 20 posts instead of 2, you could just [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) your `while` loop with a counter:

```
if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
    $counter = 0;
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post();

        /* Do post stuff here */

        $counter++;

        if( $counter == 2 ) break;
    endwhile;
}
```